# Approach to connect SAP BW to Azure?

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, sap-bw

Having a big database in SAP BW and wanting to move it to Azure for storing and querying, what is the approach you would take?

Connect SAP BW to Azure Data Factory -> Data Lake / Azure SQL Warehouse / Azure SQL Database??
What are your suggestions? Any extra details / steps would help a lot. Thanks

My final goal is then to create dashboards in PowerBI retrieving data from Azure.

Comment: Can't you just retrieve the data from SAP directly? If you're on S/4 HANA, Power BI has an S/4 connector. Alternatively, you can write a bespoke service and expose the data that way - using a URL to retrieve the data in a JSON format to be used in Power BI. Additionally, there's a BW connector in Power BI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-sap-bw-connector

Comment: Thanks, but the project is to use Azure

Comment: What sort of data sizes you talking about? Number of tables etc? Requirements for the reports, can you update the question with a bit more detail please?

Comment: What you are looking for is a popular requirement we've seen. If the volume is small (you said it's a big database but let's assume there are still relatively lightweight cubes or BEx queries), then you can use the ADF native BW connector. If scalability is a concern, check out our blog http://www.aecorsoft.com/blog/2019/1/31/use-adf-and-ssis-to-copy-data-from-sap-bw-the-comparison-of-options

Comment: Thanks everyone! In the end I was able to connect via Azure SQL Database

Comment: Hi @CosmanDana I am also trying to extract just one table data from SAP to Data Lake Gen2 via ADF. COUld you please explain how did you achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's very subjective and hard to answer.
First you must check if you have any licence issues. You can extract data from BW (Netweaver) if you have OpenHub licence. You can use HANA connection if your HANA is Enterprise.

Secondlly, about the data lake. Dou you need it? Do you have non or semi structured data, do you have data from other sources like IoT? A datalake must be carefully planned or you will end with a bigger problem in your hands.
Yes, let's do it: here are a lot of articles talking about structuring your data Lake like this one (https://medium.com/@Nicholas_Hurt/building-your-data-lake-on-adls-gen2-3f196fc6b430). You can ingest your data to a "raw" stage using data Factory, treat it to a cleansed/curated area using DataBricks or Data Factory, depending on the volume, concorrency you could need Azure Synapse/SSAS, finally you can access your data using PowerBI.

No, I only have small data: You can acess your data directly from PowerBI to BW using a PowerBI Gateway, it's the simplest way to consume BW data using PowerBI. You can Integrate it to an ADLS Gen2, isert your data on a SQLDb and finally Access using PowerBI.